# Can I make an app which has a python program file in it?

Tags: android, server, android-sqlite

I'm new to an android programming.

I'll give you an example about what my question exactly means.

I want to make an app that returns a result of web crawling/scraping(maybe 'scraping' seems more appropriate).

For example, if an app user chooses 'blockchain' as an interested topic, my app gives him back the links of articles that include a word 'blockchain' as a result of web scraping in a specific newspaper website.

I've already made a web scraping program using python. So, I want to connect this program to an android app so that whenever app user gives their interested topic through an app, I can give them back the result of web scraping.

Thank you in advance for answering my question.

+
I keep looking for the answer and it seems like my app should be linked to server and database. Then, should my web scraping python file be executed on the server side? I don't know if it's an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways are valid:

- You could generate a response server side using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or any other Framework running python code.
- Or you could use e.g. [Chaquopy-SDK](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) to execute your code on the device.